# .NET diagnostic tools?

Tags: .net

does anyone know some generic computer or/and application diagnostic tools for .NET applications?

For example a applications doesn't start on the computer of a customer. He can run the diagnostics tool which does some simple checks like:

- Which .NET Framework Versions are installed?
- Is the installed .NET Framework version valid (or maybe brocken)?
- ...

Never seen something like this for .NET specific applications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no *single* tool that I know of, but here's a handful of ones that I've used:

- For checking .NET installation, the best tool is probably Aaron Stebner's [.NET Framework Setup Verification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx).
- If your application is still failing to start, another tool to use is the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx), which will tell you if, e.g., an expected third-party file in the GAC is missing.
- If you have [instrumented your application for tracing](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/12/simple-and-easy-tracing-in-net.html), another good tool to have on hand is [TechNet/Systems Internals DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647). This one is particularly nice because you can turn tracing on and off just by modifying the `.config` (so it works well for debugging release code in a production environment). DebugView lets you observe traces live; there's another tool called the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) that takes the same traces from an XML file and displays them all pretty (it says it's for WCF, but it can be used with any XML trace file).